# SSIS Lookup matches are instead directed to my "no match" output

Tags: ssis, lookup

This is my DFT design:
[image: Package Design]

However, my matches are going to the "No Match Output" - **only** when I select "Ignore failure" will my matches proceed down the "Match Output" path.  I'm trying to figure out why.

This is the Lookup Configuration (data fields hidden for business reasons)

[image: Lookup Configuration Pt 1]
[image: Lookup Configuration Pt 2]
[image: Lookup Configuration Pt 3]

Comment: Maybe your matches aren't exact matches, because of spaces or invisible characters in the data?

Comment: Is ID numeric or a string data type? Unless you need it, don't select the table in the drop down. Write a query to pull back your lookup keys and any values you need to inject into the process. There's a performance overhead for pulling that table into memory you shouldn't pay unless required

Comment: Also, double click the line connecting the Available inputs to Availble lookup columns. Ensure you have the correct mapping

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying guys: ID is numeric, and I validated that the result imported into my staging table is the same as what existed in my reference table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out - the OLE DB Source input at the top is the table I should reference.

The Lookup function should seek out my the data I'm examining, not the data I already have imported.

Basically, I had the tables backwards.  Thanks for taking a look!